# How to implement case sensitive search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in my indexed documents where i need to search with case being sensitive. I am using the match query to fetch the results.
An example of my data document is :

```
{
  "name" : "binoy",
  "age" : 26,
  "country": "India"
}
```

Now when I give the following query:

```
{
  “query” : {
    “match” : {
      “name” : “Binoy"
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me a match for "binoy" against "Binoy". I want the search to be case sensitive. It seems by default,elasticsearch seems to go with case being insensitive. How to make the search case sensitive in elasticsearch?

Comment: "by default,elasticsearch seems to go with case being insensitive" no, it goes the way you configured your mapping (especially the analyzer for that specific field). So, how is your mapping for that field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the mapping you can define the field as not_analyzed.

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/sample" -d '{
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  }
}'

echo
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/sample/data/_mapping" -d '{
  "data": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Now if you can do normal index and do normal search , it wont analyze it and make sure it deliver case insensitive search.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the mapping you have defined for you field `name`. If you haven't defined any mapping then elasticsearch will treat it as string and use the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) (which lower-cases the tokens) to generate tokens. Your query will also use the same analyzer for search hence matching is done by lower-casing the input. That's why "Binoy" matches "binoy"

To solve it you can define a custom analyzer without `lowercase` filter and use it for your field `name`. You can define the analyzer as below

```
"analyzer": {
                "casesensitive_text": {
                    "type":         "custom",
                    "tokenizer":    "standard",
                    "filter": ["stop", "porter_stem" ]
                }
            }
```

You can define the mapping for `name` as below

```
"name": {
    "type": "string", 
    "analyzer": "casesensitive_text"
}
```

Now you can do the the search on `name`.

**note:** the analyzer above is for example purpose. You may need to change it as per your needs

Answer (score 4):

Have your mapping like:

```
PUT /whatever
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "mine": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "mine"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

meaning, no `lowercase` filter for that custom analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) which worked for my ElasticSearch 5.6:

```
{
  "template": "logstash-*",
  "settings": {
     "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
             "case_sensitive" : {
                 "type" : "custom",
                 "tokenizer":    "standard",
                 "filter": ["stop", "porter_stem" ]                    
             }
         }
     },        
     "number_of_shards": 5,
     "number_of_replicas": 1      
  },      
  "mappings": {
   "fluentd": {
     "properties": {
       "message": {
         "type": "text",
         "fields": {
           "case_sensitive": { 
             "type": "text",
             "analyzer": "case_sensitive"
           }
         }          
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

As you see, the logs are coming from FluentD and are saved into a timebased index `logstash-*`. To make sure, I can still execute wildcard queries on the `message` filed, I put a [multi-field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) on that field. Wildcard/analyzed queries can be done on `message` field and the case sensitive one on the `message.case_sensitive` field.

Comment: ```Note, the input to the stemming filter must already be in lower case, so you will need to use Lower Case Token Filter or Lower Case Tokenizer farther down the Tokenizer chain in order for this to work properly!. For example, when using custom analyzer, make sure the lowercase filter comes before the porter_stem filter in the list of filters.```